# How can I set correct index in Vue js for multidimensional array in template

Tags: loops, vue.js, indexing, counter, v-for

I have **Vue** and **multidimensional array** like this:

`myArray = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]`

and I need to get the HTML structure like this (with data-item counter always counting):

```
<div class="row" data-row="0" >
     <div class="item" data-item="0"></div>
     <div class="item" data-item="1"></div>
     <div class="item" data-item="2"></div>
</div>
<div class="row" data-row="1" >
     <div class="item" data-item="3"></div>
     <div class="item" data-item="4"></div>
     <div class="item" data-item="5"></div>
</div>
<div class="row" data-row="2" >
     <div class="item" data-item="6"></div>
     <div class="item" data-item="7"></div>
     <div class="item" data-item="8"></div>
</div>
```

**Here is my code with Vue:**

```
<div class="row" v-for="(row, index) in myArray" :data-row="index" :key="index">
     <div class="item" v-for="(item, index) in row" :data-item="index" v-bind:key="index"></div>
</div>
```

**But I get the structure like this:**

```
<div class="row" data-row="0" >
     <div class="item" data-item="0"></div>
     <div class="item" data-item="1"></div>
     <div class="item" data-item="2"></div>
</div>
<div class="row" data-row="1" >
     <div class="item" data-item="0"></div>
     <div class="item" data-item="1"></div>
     <div class="item" data-item="2"></div>
</div>
<div class="row" data-row="2" >
     <div class="item" data-item="0"></div>
     <div class="item" data-item="1"></div>
     <div class="item" data-item="2"></div>
</div>
```

how can I get **data-item** counter starts from 0 and ending to 8 in this case with Vue?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row" v-for="(row, index) in myArray" :data-row="index" :key="index">
     <div class="item" v-for="(item, subindex) in row" :data-item="index*row.length+subindex" v-bind:key="subindex"></div>
</div>
```